# Call a function inside another in Angular and add parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that makes a request to a WS and send a response in JSON format like this.

```
$scope.goRequest = function ($scope) {

        //variables for POST request

   .success(function(data) {
         //Some Code
    }

    .error(function(status)){
         //Somo code
    }
 }
```

The thing is that I need to make five requests but I dont know how to call a function inside another function and also I need to pass two parameters to goRequest that are inside my toValues function **$scope.merchMetric and $scope.topRank**

```
        $scope.topValues = function () {

        $scope.value = "topCategories";

        $scope.newValue = function (value) {
            if (value == "topCategory") {
                $scope.merchMetric = $scope.topCat
                $scope.topRank="30"
                console.log($scope.merchMetric);
            } else if (value == "topSupplier"){
                $scope.merchMetric = $scope.topSupp;
                $scope.topRank="10"
                console.log($scope.merchMetric);
            } else if (value == "topBrand") {
                $scope.merchMetric = $scope.topBrand;
                $scope.topRank="10"
                console.log($scope.merchMetric);
            } else if (value == "topSubcategory") {
                $scope.merchMetric = $scope.topSubCat
                $scope.topRank="10"
            } else if (value == "topItem") {
                $scope.merchMetric = $scope.topItem
                $scope.topRank="20"
            }

        }

    }
```

So how can I call call the goRequest function inside my top values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what the problem is, you can just call a function inside another like any other time you call a function:

```
$scope.topValues = function() {
    someService.goRequest($scope.merchMetric, $scope.topRank);
}
```

If `goRequest` is inside the same controller you don't even have to pass on `$scope.merchMetric` and `$scope.topRank`, you can just read them from there.

Comment: Thank's fotr your time 

actually it's not like a big deal the thing is that I was not sure how to do this and also doing it in the Angular way.

Im new to JS and Angular so I have a lot of questions so far :)

Comment: Thanks!

actually they are in the same controller!